# Why i cant see ''Bake data'' on my blender 2.83?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to make a fluid simulation but after all the settings done i dont see ''Bake data'' option in my physics panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to the bottom inside the domain settings to the **Cache** menu, switch the type to **"Modular"**. In version 2.83, the default cache type was changed to "Replay". This just means that the simulation will take action when you press the play button.

[image]